# Make [wcf-service], [wcfservice] synonym to [wcf]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Currently [wcfservice](/questions/tagged/wcfservice) is a approved synonym for [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) and [wcf-service](/questions/tagged/wcf-service) (45) is just  proposed.

Please accept.

Comment: Just so you know, since merges are few and far between, you can use wildcards in your favorite tags, so like this 'wcf*' will catch them all.

Answer (score 4):

That should not be done because [wcfservice](/questions/tagged/wcfservice) is already synonym of [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) which is correct. So [wcf-service](/questions/tagged/wcf-service) should be made also synonym of [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf). Imo all these tags should be merged into one [wcf](/questions/tagged/wcf) tag.

Comment: Agree with merge