# Automate merging of tags that differ only in hyphenation, except for experts-exchange

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are several cases where tags are synonymous, except for a hyphen. Apart from [experts-exchange](/questions/tagged/experts-exchange) (which I doubt has a [expertsexchange](/questions/tagged/expertsexchange) or [expert-sex-change](/questions/tagged/expert-sex-change) synonym), the tags should be automatically merged.

Examples include thread-pool versus threadpool and multi-dimensional versus multidimensional.

As to which one should be canonical: I'm more pedantic about English than most people, and even I don't care.

**Edit:** Related questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90145/merge-the-tag-httpserver-into-the-tag-http-server and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89448/merge-web-scraping-and-webscraping-tags and [Merge or ban howto and how-to tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89396/merge-or-ban-howto-and-how-to-tags) and [Make [wcf-service], [wcfservice] synonym to [wcf]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88583/rework-wcf-service-and-wcfservice) and [Tag Synonym Request: [asio]->[boost-asio]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88338/tag-synonym-request-asio-boost-asio) and [Tag merge request: [feed], [feeds], [syndication-feed], [syndicationfeed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86382/tag-merge-request-feed-feeds-syndication-feed-syndicationfeed)